# Time complexity when high degree argument is passed to function

Tags: c, for-loop, time, time-complexity

Suppose there is function called from main function as foo(n^2);
and body as

```
void foo(int n)
{
  for(int I=0 ; I<n ; I++)
    printf("");
}
```

According to my professor time complexity of above algorithm is O(n^2) whereas I believed as O(n)

Comment: `foo(n^2);`, _in code_,  is `n` exclusive-or with `2`.  Did you mean `n*n`?

Comment: That depends on the calling, since you hint at `n**2`.

Comment: of course it's `O(N)`, whatever the value passed to it. If you call it with `n*n` it will loop `n*n` times. So `O(N)`

Comment: Complexity depends on `n` passed as argument. While seeing function it is `O(n)` but value of `n` will play a role here.

Comment: Time complexity of `foo(n)` is O(n).  Time complexity of `main()` is O(n*n) or O(1) or ... depending on its contents.  The question is: Is the _algorithm_ the prof is talking about the whole unposted C program or `foo()`?

Comment: Obviously the parameter `n` and `n^2` passed to the function are different `n`s.

Comment: Agree with chux and  Eugene... I should have raised question for which n he is talking about.... inner n or outer. Thank you guys